# Assigning an Alias to @Output() and @Input() show TSLint Error

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I'm trying to assign an alias to @Output but there are TSLint error,

```
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output('bpCreated') blueprintCreated = new EventEmitter<{ serverName: string, serverContent: string }>();
  @Output('srvCreated') serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{ serverName: string, serverContent: string }>();
```

*TSLint: In the class "CockpitComponent", the directive output property "serverCreated" should not be renamed.Please, consider the following use "@Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter();" (no-output-rename)*

so when should Assign an Alias to **@Output()** and **@Input()** in Angular?

[image: Tslint error snippet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `tsLint` error, and it's clear says you should not rename it so

either

```
@Output() blueprintCreated ...
```

or

```
@Output() bpCreated ...
```

or if you **insist** to have it add this comment on top of each lines and it will ignore it

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-rename
@Output('bpCreated') blueprintCreated
```

Comment: I think a feature of the Angular framework should prevail a tslint rule.
Open `tslint.json` and add (or edit) key `no-output-rename` to have the value `false`.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk You can do it, but I don't agree, always follow best practices, so in this case option 1 and 2 are the good ones

Answer (score 2):

you can enable the tslint from Webstorm Preferences (and Suppress error for current line)

I did this in my code:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-native
@Output() close = new EventEmitter();
```